# I want to install apt package manager on my system, it doesnt have any other installer like rpl, dpkg etc. How to solve this problem

Tags: linux

I want to install apt package manager on my system, it doesnt have any other installer like iirpl, dpkg etc. How to solve this problem

I tried downloading apt offline, but unable to install as no installer is present

Comment: if your system doesn't use apt package manager, you are not going to get much from installing it.  It isn't like you can suddenly use all of the packages from debian/ubuntu because you added apt to redhat or suse.  Those packages are built with very specific versions of things that will not be the same on a different distro.  Even debian and ubuntu (based on debian) can't freely exchange packages.

Comment: Which Linux distribution ?